# Diff after merging date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

New to SAS and appreciate some help/guidance.

I have a date and time split like this in the SQL Server DB: `a1date` `a1time` `a2date` `a2time`. I would like to combine `a1date` and `a1time` into ONE and `a2date` and `a2time` into TWO and the be able to find the difference in time between ONE and TWO. The issue is that the variables are as Char datatype, which needs to be converted into Numeric datatype, I am confused how to do a diff as SAS converts it into its own date format which then cannot merge both date and time as done below. Here are three different things I have tried so far unsuccessfully. I would really appreciate any help.

```
proc sql;
select 
input(substr(strip(AcDate),1,10),MMDDYY10.)as AcDate format mmddyy10. ,
input(substr(strip(AcTime),1,10),Time10.)as AcTime format Time10. ,
input(substr(strip(ConfDate),1,10),MMDDYY10.)as ConfDate format mmddyy10. ,
input(substr(strip(ConfTime),1,10),Time10.)as ConfTime format Time10. ,
AcDate + ' ' + AcTime as Acquired,
ConfDate + ' ' + ConfTime as Confirmed,
DATEDIFF(n, Acquired, Confirmed) AS DifferenceInMinutes,
from TableName;
```

I have also tried unsuccessfully using: (errors out at first "as")

```
proc sql;
select
cast(AcDate + ' ' + AcTime AS datetime) AS ‘Acquired’,
cast(ConfDate + ' ' + ComfTime AS datetime) AS ‘Confirmed’,
DATEDIFF(n, Acquired, Confirmed) AS DifferenceInMinutes
FROM tablename
```

I have played around with this but cannot understand how to make it work.

```
DATA _null_;
INFORMAT AcDate ConfDate DATE10.
       AcTime ConfTime TIME10.
       unit $10.;
FORMAT dt1 dt2 DATETIME.;
INPUT AcTime time1 date2 time2 unit;
dt1=DHMS(date1,0,0,time1);
dt2=DHMS(date2,0,0,time2);
difference=INTCK(unit,dt1,dt2);
PUT unit= dt1= dt2= difference=;
DATALINES;
```

Comment: ... Your table design is poor for several reasons - 1) You're using strings (`CHAR`) to contain date/time types (please use appropriate types), 2) You're storing them separately (seem to actually be a timestamp, SQL Server `DateTime`), 3) Your columns names are short, somewhat cryptic, and include the data type (noise), 4) The format you seem to be storing them in isn't nicely searchable, 5) planning to convert them to numeric is likely _worse_ than strings, because it mucks with formatting.  The second block is heading in the direction you want to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS doesn't use "cast", unless you're in a passthrough connection to SQL Server.  SAS uses put and input exclusively for type conversions.  Also, SAS uses || for string concatenation,  not + (or the CAT* functions - CATS [strip+cat] and CATX [strip+cat with deliminter] most commonly).  Also, you don't enclose column names in single quotes - SAS treats single and double quotes equally, most of the time (the main exception being macros and macro variables only resolve in " " not ' ').

```
proc sql;
select
cast(AcDate + ' ' + AcTime AS datetime) AS ‘Acquired’,
cast(ConfDate + ' ' + ComfTime AS datetime) AS ‘Confirmed’,
DATEDIFF(n, Acquired, Confirmed) AS DifferenceInMinutes
FROM tablename
```

should become

```
proc sql;
select
input(catx(' ',AcDate,AcTime),MDYAMPM.) AS Acquired,
input(catx(' ',ConfDate,ComfTime),MDYAMPM.) AS Confirmed,
(calculated Acquired - calculated Confirmed)/60 AS DifferenceInMinutes
FROM tablename
```

SAS DATETIMEs are stored as a number of seconds since 1/1/1960, so the easiest way to do a DATEDIF is simply subtract the two datetime variables and divide by 60 for minutes (it's up to you if you want to use FLOOR or CEIL or ROUND or whatnot to make it an integer number of minutes).  Also, CALCULATED keyword indicates to SAS that a SQL term derives from the current query and not from the original dataset(s).

The input might not actually work exactly as you have here.  DATETIME is normally input in the format 17JAN2015:15:13:12 in SAS; there are plenty of other options, though.  I am guessing at MDYAMPM based on your code above; that inputs in the format  mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss.ss AM|PM ( http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003172027.htm ) If that's not similar to your date/time formats, you have several options.

One is to do as you were doing in the first sql step, and input them separately as date and time.  Then combine them using DHMS.  Your data step actually could be just correct - you'd have to show the actual data, though.  If you're actually going to get the data from a SQL Server table, you don't use DATALINES (which is for inputting from the code directly) or even INPUT statement (which is for that, or for inputting from text files); you should just use INPUT function.  Also data *null* does not store to a table (just temporary), so if that's your purpose go for it; usually I want a table.

Here's a test dataset.  sqltable represents your sql table, however big that is - name it properly (libname.tablename).

```
data sqltable;
input acdate $ actime $ CONFDATE $ CONFTIME $;
datalines;
09-02-2012 14:21:05 09-02-2012 16:21:05
;;;;
run;
DATA mydata;
SET sqltable;
UNIT="MINUTE";
format dt1 dt2 DATETIME.;
dt1=DHMS(input(acdate,MMDDYY10.),0,0,input(actime,TIME.));
dt2=DHMS(input(confdate,MMDDYY10.),0,0,input(conftime,TIME.));
difference=INTCK(unit,dt1,dt2); *just fill in Unit with your choice of unit, or do the math directly on the variables as shown earlier;
PUT unit= dt1= dt2= difference=;
run;
```